# MVC Code first and Ninject caching with complex mappings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, scope, ninject, code-first

My question is very similar to this one: [MVC3 tool using Entity Framework caching issues with Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949923/mvc3-tool-using-entity-framework-caching-issues-with-ninject) however my mapping is a bit more complex and when I use `InRequestScope` I get the following error:

> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

If I don't include `InRequestScope` everything works except EF Code First seems to cache my entities and it doesn't match up to the values in the Db.

Here's my ninject mapping I'm using the ninject mvc3 nuget package (without `InRequestScope`):

```
kernel.Bind<MyContext>()
  .ToSelf()
  .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", context => MvcApplication.GetConnectionStringName);

kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();

// Service Layer.
kernel.Bind<ICustomerService>().To<CustomerService>();
kernel.Bind<IMessageService>().To<MessageService>();
kernel.Bind<IUserService>().To<UserService>();

// Repository Layer.
kernel.Bind<IRepository<Customer>>().To<GenericRepository<Customer>>();
kernel.Bind<IRepository<Message>>().To<GenericRepository<Message>>();
kernel.Bind<IRepository<User>>().To<GenericRepository<User>>();

NinjectContainer.Initialize(kernel);
```

My IUnitOfWork

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    IUserService UserService { get; }
    ICustomerService CustomerService { get; }
    IMessageService MessageService { get; }
    void CommitChanges();
}
```

My UnitOfWork

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    MyContext _context;

    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    private readonly ICustomerService _customerService;
    private IMessageService _messageService;

    public UnitOfWork(IUserService userService,
        ICustomerService customerService,
        IMessageService messageService,
        MyContext context)
    {
        _userService = userService;
        _customerService = customerService;
        _messageService = messageService;

        SetContext(optimaContext);
    }

    private void SetContext(MyContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userService.Context = _context;
        _customerService.Context = _context;
        _messageService.Context = _context;
    }
    public void CommitChanges()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IUserService UserService { get { return _userService; } }
    public ICustomerService CustomerService { get { return _customerService; } }
    public IMessageService MessageService { get { return _messageService; } }
}
```

My ICustomerService

```
public interface ICustomerService
{
    DbContext Context { get; set; }
    IQueryable<Customer> All();
}
```

My CustomerService

```
public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
{
    IRepository<Customer> _customerRepo;

    public CustomerService(IRepository<Customer> customerRepo)
    {
        _customerRepo = customerRepo;
    }

    private DbContext _context;
    public DbContext Context
    {
        get { return _context; }
        set { _context = value; _customerRepo.Context = value; }
    }

    public IQueryable<Customer> All()
    {
        return _customerRepo.All();
    }
}
```

My other services follow a similar patter.

My IRepository

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class, new()
{
    DbContext Context { get; set; }

    T Single(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);
    T Find(object id);
    IQueryable<T> All();
    void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);
    void Delete(T item);
}
```

My Repository

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, new()
{
    DbContext _context;

    public DbContext Context
    {
        get { return _context; }
        set { _context = value; }
    }

    public virtual T Single(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        return All().FirstOrDefault(expression);
    }

    public virtual T Find(object id)
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> All()
    {
        return _context.Set<T>();
    }

    public virtual void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        var items = All().Where(expression);
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Delete(item);
        }
    }

    public virtual void Delete(T item)
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Remove(item);
    }
}
```

If anyone can help with the Ninject mapping and the correct way to inject classes it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem, I was using the `[Inject]` attribute with a `FilterAttribute` when the attribute was being called it was before my context had been initialised and that producted the `dbContext` error.

I followed the wiki on the ninject github site [here](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Dependency-injection-for-filters) to setup ninject on `FilterAttribute`. On issue I did have was finding the `BindFilter` method, this is hidden away `Ninject.Web.Mvc.FilterBindingSyntax` namespace.

My ninject mappings now look like:

```
kernel.Bind<MyContext>()
  .ToSelf()
  .InRequestScope()
  .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", context => MvcApplication.GetConnectionStringName);

kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();

// Service Layer.
kernel.Bind<ICustomerService>().To<CustomerService>();
kernel.Bind<IMessageService>().To<MessageService>();
kernel.Bind<IUserService>().To<UserService>();

// Repository Layer.
kernel.Bind<IRepository<Customer>>().To<GenericRepository<Customer>>();
kernel.Bind<IRepository<Message>>().To<GenericRepository<Message>>();
kernel.Bind<IRepository<User>>().To<GenericRepository<User>>();

// Attributes
kernel.BindFilter<AuthorizeWithTokenAttribute>(FilterScope.Controller, 0)
            .WhenControllerHas<AuthorizeWithTokenFilter>()
            .WithConstructorArgumentFromControllerAttribute<AuthorizeWithTokenFilter>("roles", attribute => attribute.Roles)
            .WithConstructorArgumentFromControllerAttribute<AuthorizeWithTokenFilter>("users", attribute => attribute.Users);
```